# Laravel database insert query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do simple insertion in database and im getting the following error

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no
>   array or string given

The insertion code look like this

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', array(1, 'Dayle'));
```

It's a basic query for laravel, but it won't work why?

---

Comment: Try `DB::table('users')->insert(array(1, 'Dayle'));` insert uses an array for the values and you need to specify the table to do the insert on.

Comment: did ur database connect with the laravel and do u have users table inside that database ?

Comment: I was experimenting something with codeception the tool for testing. I found the mistake, i was using the wrong database, in video tutorial for codeception they don't use laravel. So problem is wrong database. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts

Answer (score 40):

```
DB::table('users')->insert(
     array(
            'id'     =>   '1', 
            'name'   =>   'Dayle'
     )
);
```

or

```
$values = array('id' => 1,'name' => 'Dayle');
DB::table('users')->insert($values);
```

But why are you inserting an ID? Should this not be an auto incremented value?

Answer (score 1):

```
$user['id'] = 1;
$user['name'] = 'dale';

DB::table('users')->insert($user);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple like this

```
$val={
    'id_user' => '< ID_USER >',
    'title' => '< TITLE >',
    'body' => '< BODY >',
} 

Forum::create($val);
```

And its work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).