# How to insert the value into query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Do I need to insert the variable in sum(orderdets.quantity) into another variable?

```
$order =  Order::with('customer','product')
                 ->select(
                      'orders.id',
                      'orders.customer_id',
                      'orderdets.product_id',
                      DB::raw('SUM(orderdets.quantity)'))
                 ->get();
```

Comment: Not clear, plz explain more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel database insert query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423289/laravel-database-insert-query)

Comment: Go through Laravel's query builder documentation. It has everything that you are trying to do. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
$orders =  Order::with('customer','product')->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orderdets.product_id', DB::raw('SUM(orderdets.quantity) as sum'))->get();
dd($orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`AS tempName`** to get the column data by specific name. this way it can be accessed.

```
$order =  Order::with('customer','product')->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orderdets.product_id', DB::raw('SUM(orderdets.quantity) AS sumOrders'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $orders =  Order::with('customer','product')
               ->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orderdets.product_id'))
               ->get()->map(function($order){
                   $order->put('sum', $order->orderdets->sum('quantity');
            })->save();
```

This will sum all your debts and will also update orders table in one go, Although you question wasn't clear but I think you must be looking for something like this

Answer (score 0):

Please try below script in your controller.

$orders =  Order::with('customer','product')->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orderdets.product_id', DB::raw('SUM(orderdets.quantity) as sum'))->get();

return $orders;

Thanks
PHPanchal