# How to extract data from JSON and insert it into respective column in MySQL in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I am new to Laravel and working on a simple API to `insert` data into a MySQL `table`. So basically I am using a form that will accept name, email, phone, and password from the user and `insert` it into MySQL.

Is there any method in Laravel that it retrieves the key and value from the JSON data and `insert` the same data into MySQL. Below is the JSON data and table structure:

```
{
"name" : "xyz",
"email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
"password" : "12345",
"phone_number" : "1234567890",
}
```

[image: table structure]

As we can see the JSON key and the table `column` name is exactly the same so can I insert the data at once in all the fields by fetching the data from the JSON?

I don't want to `insert` data by giving them an individual key.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need to decode the JSON into an array as below. The value 'true' will ensure the data returned is an array instead of an object. (Refer: https://www.php.net/json_decode)

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Then, you can create a new row. Assuming that you're trying to create a new User, you can use [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
$user = User::create($data);
```

If you're using [Mass Assignment,](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) ensure that you've updated the model's 'fillable' attribute.

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'phone_number'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is a PHP framework, so the [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) PHP function helps us:

```
$json = json_decode($yourjson, true);

$columns = [];
$values = [];
$parameters = [];

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $columns[]=$key;
    $values[$key]=$value;
    $parameters[]=":".$key;
}

$sql = "insert into yourtable(".implode(",", $columns).") values(".implode(",", $parameters).")";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute($values);
```

The example above is using PDO.

You can also use Laravel's query builder: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

EDIT

Since there were some unclarities about `$dbh`, I share an example of PDO instantiation taken from the documentation.

```
<?php
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: I am getting this error **ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: @Pooja if $json is an array, then you should not have any problems. So, can you tell me what the value of $json is just before the foreach?

Comment: I am getting no value

Comment: @Pooja what do you have in $yourjson?

Comment: I am passing $request, Where I am getting the JSON. Let me check my statement. Thanks for the help @Lajos

Comment: @Pooja I'm absolutely sure no problem should be at the place where you have a problem at, so the issue must be some detail missed in your code that I forgot to explain.

Comment: Okk I will look for it. Again Thanks

Comment: What is $dbh? @Lajos

Comment: @Pooja it's a shorthand for database handler. It could have a different name, for example $pdo, as used here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert

Comment: It's not a standard naming, I should have not assumed that this is clear, thanks for the question.

Comment: Undefined variable: dbh. Now I am getting this error, So asked what is dbh?

Comment: @Pooja $dbh is a variable that stands for database handler. You need to instantiate PDO, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo(); **this I found in laravel documentation**

Comment: No. But If I use your suggested method then I will have to make a new php file that store the DB connection

Comment: @Pooja yes, that's true. If you create a new file for this purpose, then it will be reusable and you can apply some protection levels to it.

Comment: Ok I will do that, But I think Laravel already have a file that is used for the DB Connection that is .env file

Comment: @Pooja I see. In that case you can probably execute it like at this place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423289/laravel-database-insert-query

Comment: @Pooja I didn't work with Laravel yet, but apparently something like this should work: DB::table('yourtable')->insert($values); Try this instead of the last three rows in my code. This would be the more Laravel-like way to execute an insert than the PDO-like way I described originally in my answer.